# I can read a :before {content:'...'} string via JavaScript (getComputedStyle), but this string behaves weirdly

Tags: javascript, css

I have the follwing setup. I create a `<div>`, attach the term "before" through the pseudo-selector `:before` and read that value by using `getComputedStyle`.

This works, I get the term (which in my case is "before") successfully, it is of type "string". (See the console output.)

The comparison of that string with a given string returns the expected `true`, but only in Safari, [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPWdqB) and here, in the "Run code snippet"-Environment!

It does NOT work in Chrome, Firefox, or IE. The comparison of the match there returns `false`.

What could be the reasons for it?

Why does this simple string-comparison not work?

The three relevant snippets of code look like this:

```js
var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.pseudo'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content');
console.log('content: ' + content); // "before"
console.log('typeof content: ' + typeof content); // string
console.log(content == "before"); // false
document.write(content == "before"); // false
```

```css
div.pseudo:before {
  content: "before";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pseudo">
  Div with pseudo :before content.
</div>
```

Comment: It returns `true` on Codepen for me in Chrome

Comment: Quick test on some browsers: IE returns 'false' , google chrome 'true', Firefox: 'false'

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn You are right!! My fault, sorry. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Firefox: `content == '"before"'` [returns true](http://jsfiddle.net/bstzomzk/). (Your content equals the string + the quotes surrounding it.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found that different browsers treat `getPropertyValue` for `content` differently. Some browsers return literal quotes in the string, others don't.

Here is the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47b9krux/2/)** that I used to test the behaviour across different browsers. The results below:

```
                                 | before | "before"
---------------------------------+--------+---------
Chrome 42.0.2311.135             | true   | false 
Chrome Canary 44.0.2394.0        | false  | true 
Firefox 37.0.2                   | false  | true
Firefox Developer Edition 39.0a2 | false  | true
Internet Explorer 11.09          | false  | true
Safari 8.0.5                     | true   | false
Opera 29.0.1795.47               | true   | false
```

Markup:

```
<div class="pseudo">Div with pseudo :before content.</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.pseudo:before {
    content:'before';
    color: red;
}
```

The JS:

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.pseudo'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content');

console.log(content == "before");
console.log(content == '"before"');
```

Comment: This is a nice and complete answer!

Comment: It's worth noting that Chrome (and some other browsers probably, but I only tested this in Chrome 60) not only returns the quotes around the string, but also leaves escape sequences (like `\"`, ``\\`` or `\f10c`) un-parsed. It simply gives you the raw string, as it stands in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has `"` around the text, replace `"` with `''`, i.e. remove them.

```js
var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.pseudo'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content');
console.log('content: ' + content); // "before"
console.log('typeof content: ' + typeof content); // string
console.log(content == "before"); // false
document.write(content.replace(/"/g, '') == "before"); // true
```

```css
div.pseudo:before {
  content: "before";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pseudo">
  Div with pseudo :before content.
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to edit your first line, it's difficult to see the differences between `"` and `'  '`

Comment: You mean Firefox has double quotes around the text, replace the double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: @Psioniax No, meant to remove them, updated the format in the answer.

Comment: Actually I was stating that you can't differentiate the double quotes from the single ones the way you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.pseudo'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content');
console.log('content: ' + content); // "before"
console.log('typeof content: ' + typeof content); // string
console.log(content == "before"); // false
document.write(content == "before"); // false
```

```css
div.pseudo:before {
  content: "before";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pseudo">
  Div with pseudo :before content.
</div>
```

Firefox: `content == '"' + 'text' + '"'` returns true
Chrome: `content == text` returns true
Opera: `content == text` returns true
Safari: `content == text` returns true
<s>IE:</s>  (I can't seem to make it work in IE)

Comment: you came up with the solution first. Nevertheless i accepted mrkiffie answer because it's so nicely formatted. I hope, your ok with that.

Comment: Haha, don't worry about it, I like his answer more too!