# Access FontAwesome unicode from class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

When inspecting the element, let's say that I have this HTML.

```
<i class="fa fa-user">
   ::before
</i>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-user::before {
    content: "\f007";
}
```

Here I am getting the content of fa-user

```
    $('.fa-user').each(function(){
        var unicode = window.getComputedStyle(this,':before').content;
        console.log(unicode);
    });
```

The problem is that unicode variable is rendered as icon (symbol).

[image]

I want it to be string -> "\f007"

I also tried this but it just returns some non related number, in this case it's number 22

`var unicode = window.getComputedStyle(this,':before').content.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some browsers wrap the `.content` value with quotes ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100435/i-can-read-a-before-content-string-via-javascript-getcomputedstyle-b)). You need to remove them before getting the first character:

```js
$('.fa-user').each(function() {
  var unicode = window.getComputedStyle(this, ':before').content
                                                        .replace(/'|"/g, '') // <-----
                                                        .charCodeAt(0)
                                                        .toString(16);
  console.log("\\" + unicode);
});
```

```css
.fa-user::before { content: "\f007"; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!